# Model some logarithmic looking data in R

Tags: r, modeling

I have the following data in R

```
x <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.9,1)
y <- c(90,96,97.7,99.3,99.65,99.95,100)
```

I'm trying to find a logarithmic equation that best fits these points. I'm not sure what the equation would look like, but probably something like one of these

- a*log(x)+b
- (a*log(x)+b)/(log(x)+c)
- a*log(b*x)+c
- etc

What kind of curve do you think best fits this data. And how can I find out?

Comment: The question still doesn't belong here. i vote to close.

Comment: I agree the question is somewhat vague. Maybe the poster could elaborate it ?

Comment: Okay if the data is being fit to a statistical model then it is okay for here.

Comment: All of the models you've listed have the same general form: $$y = \frac{\beta_1 \log\left(\beta_2 x\right)+\beta_3}{\beta_4 \log\left(\beta_5 x\right)+\beta_6}+\epsilon$$ Might it be possible to fit the full model, then remove coefficients based on estimates and standard errors? Though that is a seven-parameter model and you have seven data points...

Comment: I agree with @Max 's last point. Your models are getting too complex for your data.

Comment: (+1) for @Max. So the fit is probably perfect with seven parameters and seven data values. Actually this exactly solves the question !

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Fitting the model above gives a fairly sizable sum of squares. With an intercept term added, the sum of squares gets much closer to zero but it's still not exact. I know that a seven parameter linear model will fit the data exactly, but is that actually the case for a nonlinear model?

Comment: http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fit a linear regression model as follows:

```
f <- function(x) a*log(x)+b
fit <- lm(y~I(f(x)))
summary(fit)
```

Then examine the fitted model for every candidate function `f`.